# python: logging and unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging

I've got a problem in an unittest output in my project. That isn't a big issue but I don't understand reasons and want to research ones.

Environment:

1) conf.py contains the definition of the logger

```
fh = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILE_NAME)
ff = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - (message)s')
fh.setFormatter(ff)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
cf = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(cf)

lg = logging.getLogger('logger')
lg.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
lg.addHandler(ch)
lg.addHandler(fh)
```

2) modules of the app import lg from the conf and use it to collect log events

3) also I added unittest for a one of app module

4) when I run tests

```
python3 -m unittest -v project/tests/test-module.py
```

I got the next console output:

```
test_init_ok (project.tests.test-module.TestReportData) ... ok
test_set_report (project.tests.test-module.TestReportData) ... DEBUG - Report is {} ok
```

I don't have any ideas why the last message from an original sys.stdout (from the conf) is sent to the unittest stream.

Also I'll be glad to get advices of better practices.

Comment: "modules of the app import lg from the conf " => they shouldn't actually. Modules should only do `import logging; logger = logging.getLogger(<name>)` (usually using the magic variable `__name__`).

Comment: Also you may want to use `logging.DictConfig` which is much more friendly than manual config.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers could you explain "they shouldn't actually." please? or do you have references? thank you for the 'DictConfig' I just read documentation about it.

Comment: One of the points of the way the logging lib works is to decouple logger's use (library code) from configuration (application). This allow libraries to be totally independant of the apps using them, and applications to configure the logging how they want.

Comment: Also since loggers form a hierarchy based on the name with the "root" logger at the top (so "foo.bar.bazz" is a child of "foo.bar" which is a child of "foo" which is a child of "root" - hence the canonical use of the `__name__` variable) and, by default, child loggers propagate to their parent, you can just configure the root logger with sensible default, and override the config for a given child (and it's own children) as you see fit.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers that's good, thank you. I tried to do how you told me and a part of extra messages left. I think I can fix the issue. Also I'll re-read the logging docs)